# Recommendation for designing authentication mechanism

Tags: node.js, flutter, authentication, jwt, authorization

I'm building an app where there will be 2 roles, namely User and Agent. A user can rent a car, rent a room and other related operations. An Agent is just one level higher, where he can act on behalf of multiple users he/she is an agent for. So the agent can rent a car, rent a room on behalf of its user it is an agent for. So now the backend is nodejs and I was thinking of using JWT tokens for authentication and authorization purposes. The problem arises on how I can differentiate if it is an actual user or an agent that is performing the actions, and accordingly check if they are authorized.

Comment: leverage on very high-level state management to the extent you can manage the state (user and agent), with model objects that grants for each type of user.

Comment: For authorisation I think you can look into [OPA](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/) to support your JWT based mechanism.